# How to escape quotes in a string that assigns a method to onclick with a parameter?

Tags: php, string

I have a string that contains HTML-Code. And within that string I am assigning a method WITH AN ARGUMENT to the onclick-attribute. This attribute needs to be a string though.

This is the code.
[image]

This is how it looks like in HTML.
[image]

This is how it should look like in HTML.
[image]

I tried to put double quotes before and after, escape them, escape them with multiple backslahes, and many other things, nothing works. All ideas are appreaciated. :-)

Comment: Code should not be included as an image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [stripslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php). Note however, that you can not use the same double quote (`"`) or single qoutes (`'`) for both the attribute assignment AND the string definition for the parameter. Therefore you want your result to look something like: `onclick="removeTag('naruto')"`.

If you have them as double quotes in your original string (i.e. `$row['description']`), you can replace those, all put together like this:

```
echo 'blabla <a href="#" onclick="removeTag(' . str_replace('"', '\'', stripslashes($row['description'])) . ')">';
```

A tiny bit simpler approach might be to just trim double quotes and add your own single qoutes:

```
echo 'blabla <a href="#" onclick="removeTag(\'' . trim(stripslashes($row['description']), '"') . '\')">';
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed, I will take a further look into it to understand it completely but atleast it already fixed the problem lol. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can also use onclick without quotes  just put it last property in the html tag  
`echo 'blabla <a href="#" onclick=alert("'.$row['description'].'")>call removeTag</a>';`